# Angular returning data from multiple modals

Tags: angular

I'm having problems reading data from two (separate) modals.

I started by having one modal on my page and it worked perfectly, I could read the data returned from it, display it on a table and edit/delete each element individually.

However when I added the second modal this one didn't behave the same. The first one still works but the second one either prints out an error or duplicates the last element added from the first modal.

Here's the code of my component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

...

Component({
  selector: 'app-create-technique',
  templateUrl: './create-technique.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-technique.component.scss']
})
export class CreateTechniqueComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  loading         : boolean = false;
  currentEditing  : number = -1;
  bsModalRef      : BsModalRef;
  bsModalRefTask  : BsModalRef;
  modalSub        : Subscription;
  modalTSub       : Subscription;

...

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    private modalServiceTask: BsModalService,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.createHandler();


    this.handleStuct();
    }

   ngOnDestroy() {
     this.destroyHandler();
   }

    addLearningObjective() {
      this.bsModalRef = this.setupModal();
    }

    defineStruct() {
      this.bsModalRefTask = this.setupModalTask();
    }

    private setupModal() : BsModalRef {
      let ref = this.modalService.show(CreateLearningobjectiveComponent, {class: 'modal-lg'});
      ref.content.behaviour_cat = this.behaviour_cat;
      return ref;
    }

    private setupModalTask() : BsModalRef {
      let ref = this.modalServiceTask.show(CreateTaskComponent, {class: 'modal-lg'});
      return ref;
    }

    private destroyHandler() {
      this.modalSub.unsubscribe();
    }

    private createHandler() {
      this.modalSub = this.modalService.onHide.subscribe(reason => {
        if (reason || this.bsModalRef.content.canceled) { // Backdrop click
          return;
        }

        let lo = this.transformModalData(this.bsModalRef.content.form);

        if (this.currentEditing !== -1) {
          this.form.learning_objectives[this.currentEditing] = lo;
          this.currentEditing = -1;
        } else {
          this.form.learning_objectives.push(lo);
        }

      });


    }

    private handleStuct() {
      this.modalTSub = this.modalServiceTask.onHide.subscribe(reason => {
        if (reason || this.bsModalRefTask.content.canceled) { // Backdrop click
          return;
        }

        let struct = this.transformModalData(this.bsModalRefTask.content.techniqueStruct.value);


        this.form.structure = Object.assign({}, struct);
        console.log(this.form.structure);

      });
    }

    private transformModalData(data: any) {
      return data;
    }
```

bsModalRefTask, modalTSub and modalServiceTask all refer to the second, non-working modal.

Is it not possible to do what I'm trying to do or if it is how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide HTML code to track the issue

Answer (score 0):

> bsModalRefTask, modalTSub and modalServiceTask all refer to the second, non-working modal.

In the code you shared both `modalService` and `modalServiceTask` refer to the same service: `BsModalService`. i.e. `this.modalService === this.modalServiceTask`. There's no reason to inject the same service twice, so far as I am aware.

Also `this.modalService.onHide` and `this.modalServiceTask.onHide` are the same. I imagine they are both going to trigger when any model fires an `onHide` event.

I'm not familiar with `'ngx-bootstrap/modal'`, but I'm guessing that either it doesn't support multiple modals or you are using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/4490